# Liferay - Retrieving data by querying directly

Tags: mysql, liferay, data-retrieval

I have many columns I need to retrieve from the database (not from Lucene) and each column is sortable and there are quite a few filter options.

Correct me if I'm wrong but custom SQL does not allow variable columns, and each variation would need a separate custom SQL.

While it is possible through custom SQL, the number of permutations is immense. Is there a way to construct my own query based on some conditions and retrieve the data accordingly?

Dynamic query is not possible as the query is a bit complex.

Comment: I am not sure what do you mean by "variable columns," but if it is what I'm thinking it is, you can use custom queries (as in https://web.liferay.com/community/wiki/-/wiki/Main/Custom+queries+in+Liferay) to store the large bulk of the query, and then append or replace parts you want to be different.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
DataSource liferayDataSource = InfrastructureUtil.getDataSource();
  Connection connection = null;
  try {
    connection = liferayDataSource.getConnection();
  } catch (SQLException e1) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e1.printStackTrace();
  }
```

Set the connection of the prepared statement to the one obtained above and continue as per usual JDBC usage.